# Phone number validation regex for length and numeric values

Tags: java, regex

I have to validate a phone number based on the following criteria,

```
It should only take numeric values.
Minimum 10 and Maximum 15
```

How can I write a regular expression in java satisfying the above? I am new to regular expressions.

Comment: Share what have you tried with us. SO is for seeking help, not getting your work done.

Comment: do you have a specific format for phone number ? Why not simply `^\d{10,15}$`

Comment: I hope you realize that phone numbers according to the ITU recommendations can have spaces and other characters. Particularly they can start with a '+' (to represent the international access code that differs per country you are calling from). Whoever setup the criteria has to get around the globe some more.

Comment: and may have more or fewer numbers to be legal depending on locality and scope (e.g. where I live a number would be 7 long if dialed locally, 10 nationally, 12 internationally, and mobile numbers different again).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the regular expression

```
^\\d{10,15}$
```

Here `\d` is a [predefined character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html) for digits
`{10, 15}` [quantifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) stands for a repeat of 10 to 15 times of the previous pattern

Ex:

```
String input = "1234567890";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d{10,15}$");
if (pattern.matcher(input).find()) {
    System.out.println("Valid");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
\\d{10,15}
```

`\d` matches a digit (preceding \ is for escaping)

`{10,15}` allows minimum 10 and maximum 15 occurrence of preceding pattern

Answer (score 0):

\d is for number 0-9

```
(\d){10,15}
```